# HtmlDocument get a incomplete page

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am doing a small web scraping project, and I am having a problem with the function that takes the html code. **The web that I inspect in the browser is different from the web that downloads the method (for the same URL).**

I have tried to improve the coding process, but to no avail. The same thing happens for "i=2".

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string prefixurl = "https://www.aaabbbcccdddeee.de/en/do-business-with-finland/finnish-suppliers/finnish-suppliers-results?query=africa";


            for (int i = 1; i < 18; i++)
            {
                string url = prefixurl;
                if (i > 1)
                {
                    url = prefixurl + "&page=" + i;
                }

                var doc = GetDocument(url);
                var links = GetBusinessLinks(url);
                List<Empresa> empresas = GetBusiness(links);
                Export(empresas);
                
            }
            
        }

static List<string> GetBusinessLinks(string url)
        {
            var doc = GetDocument(url);
            var linkNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/section/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]//a");
            
            // //a[@class=\"btn bf-ghost-button\"]
            var baseUri= new Uri(url);
            var links = new List<string>();

//The problem its there, in the incomplete page the program haven't found nodes            
            foreach (var node in linkNodes)
            {
                var link = node.Attributes["href"].Value;
                bool business = link.Contains("companies");
                if (business)
                {
                    link = new Uri(baseUri, link).AbsoluteUri;
                    links.Add(link);
                }    
            }
            return links;
        }
static HtmlDocument GetDocument(string url)
        {
            var web = new HtmlWeb();

            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument()
            {
                OptionDefaultStreamEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
            };
            doc = web.Load(url);
            return doc;
        }

´´´
```

Comment: *the page I see in the browser is different than the one downloaded with the method* - How so?

Comment: Perhaps javascript is not enabled for one of your approaches, so the page transformations don't occur

Comment: I am proving now with selenium..

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion has made me suspect where I should continue looking, thanks.
I have used PupperSharp in non-headless mode.

https://betterprogramming.pub/web-scraping-using-c-and-net-d99a085dace2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).